# Images not loading in React app with Webpack despite having file loaders (url-loader)

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, babeljs, webpack-file-loader

I have a React app that uses Webpack and Babel. I am trying to load an image anyway possible (svg, png...) but I keep getting the error "Unexpected character '�' (1:0) > 1 | �PNG". I installed url-loader (npm install url-loader --save-dev) which is supposed to help load images when using Webpack. Nothing has changed.

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
const {NODE_ENV} = process.env;

module.exports = {
  mode: NODE_ENV === 'production' ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
  entry: ['./client/index.js'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 25000
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

};
```

This is how I was trying to load my image:

```
import hiker from './hiker.png';
<img src={hiker} />
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can you show files architecture?

Comment: @Muath which ones? It is finding the image well, just can't dissect it:(

Comment: I'd like to help, but too many variables to consider. Please post a github link.

Comment: @MattCarlotta https://github.com/emmaorhun/intergalactic-ecommerce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here. First, you're using `babel-node` that's pointing to the `index.js`. If you want it to point to your webpack config, then you'll need to remove `index.js` from the `package.json`'s dev `scripts`:

```
"dev": "nodemon --exec babel-node",
```

And rename `webpack.config.js` to `babel.config.js`.

Unfortunately, there's also quite a bit more work required to get your project up-and-running. It appears that this setup uses some `server-side-rendering` configuration. Admittedly, I've never used `koa`, so I can't be of much help here.

It also appears to be a bit outdated, and someone [updated it and included a walkthrough](https://github.com/juliantrueflynn/shopify-koa-app-example/tree/master/walkthrough).

That said, I'd recommend steering toward a new-developer friendly boilerplate if you're just learning.

I'd suggest starting with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), which obscures a lot of this webpack configuration.

Or, you can download my [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/react-starter-kit), which has an exposed webpack configuration that you can play around with (if desired) and utilizes `webpack-dev-server` for development and `webpack` with a very simple `express` configuration for production.

Up to you.

Good luck!